# Return start and end of year given any year

Tags: c#, datetime, date-math, date-manipulation

I need two or one (out) C# method that will take any datetime and return the start date of year and end date of year for that year.

Comment: What do you mean by start date of year? It will always be Jan 1 and Dec 31 right?

Comment: The start date is Jan 1 and the end date is Dec 31. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm stupid; I guess (my brain has a corrupt stack)

Comment: +1 You might feel stupid - but you're not. You're even getting points!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
void Dates(DateTime d, out DateTime b, out DateTime e)
{
    b = new DateTime(d.Year, 1, 1);
    e = new DateTime(d.Year, 12, 31);
}
```

Comment: For 6 years I had typo in the answer, got 20 points, and nobody noticed that. Nice :-)

Comment: also this will not include 12/31 if the time is important, than should be e = ...AddTicks(-1).AddDays(1)

Answer (score 9):

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);
```